# Is there any way to trigger iOS built-in photo editor for saved image in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

The iOS app saves an image to photo library and I need to display a clickable floating image preview that shows a native image editor on click (exactly like after taking a screenshot in iOS)

Is there any API in UIKit to accomplish that without extra pods?

Comment: Have you tried UIDocumentInteractionController? 
[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller)